# "Я не ненавижу" или "Я ни ненавижу"

Tags: орфография, глаголы, не-или-ни

*Я не ненавижу это.*
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в данном случае должно выглядеть отрицание: через "не" или через "ни"?

Comment: Как обычно, через двойное не: я не не люблю это; я не не могу это; я не ненавижу это.

Comment: Конечно, здесь именно отрицание, можно сделать замену: Я не испытываю ненависти к этому. С другой стороны,  в таком коротком предложении  сочетание выглядит стилистически некорректно – плохо читается и воспринимается. В приведенных в ответе примерах в более распространенных случаях  делается пауза, сочетание и читается, и выглядит лучше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Я **не** ненавижу это.*
Такая ситуация в предложении (с двумя "не") называется двойным отрицанием.
Оно придает сочетанию или всему предложению смысл утверждения:
не мог не заметить (= заметил);
не мог не сказать (= сказал);
нельзя не сознаться (= надо сознаться).

Во избежание ошибок обычно подбирают синонимы к словам или выражениям (сложность может вызвать то, что глагол "ненавидеть" без "не" не употребляется):
не ненавижу = люблю, терплю, выношу.

В конце концов ― ещё бы им меня **не ненавидеть**! [А. И. Солженицын. Бодался теленок с дубом (1967-1974)]
Главное же ― прощением: есть только одно средство **не ненавидеть** тех, которые делают нам зло и обиды, ― это делать им добро; если и не переменишь их, то зато себя обуздаешь. [Л. Н. Толстой. Путь жизни (1910)]

Написание "ни ненавижу", конечно же, тоже возможно — при условии, что в предложении имеется парная частица "ни".

Это ― страсть независимости, а страсть **нельзя ни любить, ни ненавидеть**. [В. А. Каверин. Перед зеркалом (1965-1970)]
В злых людях бывает так много доброго, в смешных ― так много великого, что порой **не решаешься ни ненавидеть** их, **ни насмехаться** над ними. [Н. К. Чуковский. Танталэна (1925)]

[НЕ и НИ](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.7)